# How do I use a i2c port expander to read buttons with pull ups and inverting the resulting uint16_t?

Tags: programming, arduino-leonardo

I am using a mcp23017 to read button presses for my joystick project and am using the internal pullup to minimize complications. Is there a way to invert all the bits in the uint16_t so i can send the values as normally off?

I'm using [this Adafruit library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library).

And the reading code: `uint16_t buttons = mcp.readGPIOAB();`

Answer (score 3):

The inversion operator in C++ is `~`.

```
Serial.print(buttons, BIN);
Serial.print(~buttons, BIN);
```

Comment: Amazing dude thanks!!! I added a ~ in front of mcp.digitalReadGPIOAB(); and that has done the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino! You can click the "accept" button (the green checkmark by the answer) to mark that this solution worked. Thanks! :)